# AR app for androids

Tags: android, build, augmented-reality

I'm trying to build an Augmented Reality application for androids. I just want it to show some 3d models when it recognizes my different markers.

I used this excellent SDK, https://ar.qualcomm.at/qdevnet/sdk and followed the steps, but unfortunately when I created the application and ran it on my android, it showed a message "Your device is not supported". That's probably because that guide is for 2.1 androids, and mine is 2.2

Is there any way to "convert" it? I just want to make it play on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

*Is there any way to "convert" it? I just want to make it play on my phone.*

Not that I know of. The QCAR SDK actually checks for device compatibility based on explicit conditions (e.g. a snapdragon processor) and fails to initialize if the device is not supported. There's a list of supported devices available on their dev forum - https://ar.qualcomm.at/qdevnet/forums

Answer (score 0):

Most Android (and iOS) devices are now supported by QCAR SDK.